# kbmMW DXE8 updating connected clients

Tags: android, ios, delphi

Using Delphi XE8 Enterprise

Does anyone have an example that demonstrates how to have connected clients that are connected to a kbmMW server in stateful mode be automatically updated with data changes submitted by another client?

So client A updates a row in the orders table or adds a new order to the orders table.

Clients B, C, and D are statefully connected and have their local data objects updated by the server with the changes from client A automagically?

Is this doable with kbmMW? Is there a mechanism already provided for this or would it require significant coding?

Secondly, is there a recommended way to update datasets on low performance mobile devices that will minimize or eliminate GUI update delays? I've tried pulling the data in a background thread using a generic method, then setting memtable.disablecontrols, then copying the query results to a local in memory dataset by synchronizing the thread.

Even with a quad core snapdragon 2.5ghz processor the delay/GUI freeze is quite noticable.

It seems obvious that I should be only updating changed values. What would be the best/fastest way to do this with a TkbmMemTable or TkbmMWClientQuery?

Locate?
Setting a filter based on key values?
Accessing the underlying delta directly?

Using TMSFMXGrid, kbmMW 4.90, Android 4.4, 5, will be porting to iOS 4, 5 & 6.

Thanks.

Comment: The author of KBM MW, Kim Madsen might be the best person to answer this.  He was around here a few days ago, iirc, so maybe you'll get lucky.  Or contact C4D direct ...

Comment: Thanks I posted on the kbmMW newsgroup and got no response so I thought I'd try here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Enterprise Edition, I would choose to use the WIB (messaging) transports client side and server side.

If your data is updated via resolving, then one way is to hook into the resolvers OnSubInsert/OnSubDelete/OnSubModify events which are called individually for each sub operation (table) during resolving.

You can then push either a notification that a change has happened to clients and let them request a new complete dataset, or you can push the delta values to the client, and let them locally update their datasets.

If your user data is updated via a business method (PerformCreateCustomer... etc) then you put your notification code in there, again either by sending an information to all connected clients to request a new dataset (potentially filtered by an ID of the updated data, that you also may provide) from their clients, or by pushing only the modifications to the clients.

It the client datasets are a one to one match with server side datasets (ie structure is same and only one table is involved), you can even hook at the WIB OnRequest method, grab the userdata stream (which contains the delta) and forward that to the other clients, and let a custom resolver handle the resolving for your on the updated dataset.

In fact you *could* choose to let all clients subscribe for REQ.*.*.servicename.*.RESOLVE.> subject, and tell the server to auto relay subscribed messages (AutoRelay=true).

Then when any one client sends a delta to the server to resolve, all other clients will also be getting the same delta.
The clients can then pick the delta from the userdata stream, and via a custom deltahandler update their own local datasets.

The problem in all situations where you deal with delta values only, is not so much the basics, its the situations where multiple clients do something at the same time on the same data.
Then you will have conflicts and if you do not handle those, you will end up in the clients have different understanding of what the dataset contents should look like.

Its possible to code for the various situations in a very precise way, so it will work stably, but its not trivial.

The most stable way is usually to just notify clients about changes on a larger level, and let them poll the server for new data, filtered down on a specific ID (customer ID or something).

best regards
Kim/C4D

Comment: Thanks Kim that makes a lot of sense. I worked in the Asta world many years ago and remember sending coded messages back and forth. I thought about doing something similar here, but didn't know if you had implemented a more elegant mechanism or not. I agree with you that it's best to let the concurrency issues be handled by the DB server, send a notification to the interested clients, and have them do a pull.

Comment: These events that you are referring to, OnSubxxx, where are they accessed?

Comment: Via the TkbmMWxxxResolver component on the server side.

Comment: I don't see any mention of 'WIB' in the help file, nor do I find any WIB messaging components from the installation into DX Seattle. I'm using both enterprise kbmMW and enterprise DX. Where do I find these transports?

Comment: If you have installed kbmMW Enterprise Edition, you should have TkbmMWTCPIPIndyMessagingServerTransport, TkbmMWTCPIPIndyMessagingClientTransport and ditto UDP. Depending on your installation, you may have more like TkbmMW....SynapseMessaging... etc.